# How to find and link CUDA libraries using CMake 3.15 and later?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I'm using CMake 3.15-rc3 on my Unix-like system.

I need to link a program I'm building with several of the CUDA libraries, including `cublas`, `cufft`, `cusolver`, `curand`, `nppicc`, `nppial`, `nppist`, `nppidei`, `nppig`, `nppitc`, `npps`.

Based on what I found online, I need to do something like this:

```
add_executable(test benchmark.cpp)
find_package(CUDALibs)
target_link_libraries(test CUDA::cudart CUDA::cublas CUDA::cufft CUDA::cusolver CUDA::curand CUDA::nppicc CUDA::nppial CUDA::nppist CUDA::nppidei CUDA::nppig CUDA::nppitc CUDA::npps)
```

When I run `make` I get the following error:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindCUDALibs.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "CUDALibs",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "CUDALibs" with any
  of the following names:

    CUDALibsConfig.cmake
    cudalibs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "CUDALibs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "CUDALibs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "CUDALibs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

So looks like I need a `CUDALibsConfig.cmake` file. Where do I get this file and how to I tell cmake to use it?

If I use the following it works:

```
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(run_benchmarks tf libmxnet.so ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_cusparse_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_npp_LIBRARY})
```

But according to [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDA.html) `find_package(cuda)` is deprecated, so I want to learn the proper usage.

**Edit**
I tried what was suggested in one of the responses.
I added `CUDA` to the project `LANGUAGES`:

```
project(
        test_project
        DESCRIPTION "Test project"
        LANGUAGES CXX CUDA
        )
```

And then I used `find_package( FindCUDAToolkit REQUIRED)`

However, when I run cmake I get the following errors:

```
 nchafni   dev  …  sample_code  benchmarks  build  1  cmake ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 10.1.243
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin/nvcc
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin/nvcc -- works
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindFindCUDAToolkit.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "FindCUDAToolkit", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "FindCUDAToolkit"
  with any of the following names:

    FindCUDAToolkitConfig.cmake
    findcudatoolkit-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "FindCUDAToolkit" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "FindCUDAToolkit_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "FindCUDAToolkit" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The modern way to do it is documented in the link you posted, have you tried that?

Comment: What version of CMake are you using?

Comment: @einpoklum cmake version 3.15.0-rc3

Comment: @cyrusbehr: Note that Kitware revamped the way you find CUDA stuff sometime between CMake 3.17 and 3.19.

Comment: Ok, let me upgrade my cmake and try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find_package(CUDA)` is deprecated for the case of programs written in CUDA / compiled with a CUDA compiler (e.g. NVCC). The documentation page [says](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/module/FindCUDA.html) (emphasis mine):

> It is no longer necessary to use this module or call `find_package(CUDA)` **for
> compiling CUDA code**. Instead, list CUDA among the languages named in
> the top-level call to the `project()` command, or call the
> `enable_language()` command with CUDA. Then one can add CUDA (`.cu`)
> sources to programs directly in calls to `add_library()` and
> `add_executable()`.

But `find_package(CUDA)` was not really deprecated - as of CMake version 3.15 - for C++ code which simply uses CUDA-enabled/CUDA-bundled/CUDA-utilizing libraries.

In CMake 3.17, a new macro/command was introduced: [`FindCUDAToolkit()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html#module:FindCUDAToolkit) (and this, `find_package(CUDAToolkit)`. You can't use that with your version of CMake;  `find_package(CUDA)` will do just fine, even if it's a bit clunky and outdated.

**Edit:** It is actually very easy to upgrade to a newer CMake version: KitWare offer binary [releases](https://cmake.org/download/) which have very little dependencies. On a Linux system they would be:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1
    libdl.so.2
    librt.so.1
    libpthread.so.0
    libm.so.6
    libc.so.6
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

... and you would be hard-pressed to find a system without these. Also, even when installed under an arbitrary path, CMake will be able to differentiate between its version of shared files and whatever the system version of CMake uses. So - no reason to stick with the old version.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked says that you need to add `CUDA` to the list of languages in your `project()` command. And to find CUDA libraries it says to use [FindCUDAToolkit](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html) module, not that `CUDALibs`.

Comment: So I tried what you suggested, added CUDA to project LANGUAGES, then added `find_package( FindCUDAToolkit REQUIRED)` but when I run CMake I get the following error: 
```
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "FindCUDAToolkit"
  with any of the following names:

    FindCUDAToolkitConfig.cmake
    findcudatoolkit-config.cmake

```

Comment: This won't work with OP's version of CMake.