# undefined reference to `cuMemAlloc_v2'

Tags: cmake, compiler-errors, cuda, undefined-reference

I need to modify linux rdma-core driver and add some cuda-related functions; firstly, `cuMemAlloc`.
I have changed the CMake file in the driver to include the `cuda.h` header file. But when I compile the driver, I get `undefined reference to` error

In the CMakeLists.txt file, I have included

```
project(rdma-core LANGUAGES CUDA C CXX)
FIND_PACKAGE(CUDA 12.2 REQUIRED)
```

and `-I/usr/local/cuda-12.2/include -lcuda` to

```
RDMA_AddOptCFlag(CMAKE_C_FLAGS HAVE_C_WARNINGS
  "-Wall -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -I/usr/local/cuda-12.2/include -lcuda")
```

Although cuda.h is successfully found, I get the following compilation error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/mlx5.dir/verbs.c.o: in function `mlx5_alloc_dyn_uar':
/home/nurlan/rdma-core/providers/mlx5/verbs.c:235: undefined reference to `cuMemAlloc_v2'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/nurlan/rdma-core/providers/mlx5/verbs.c:235: undefined reference to `cuMemAlloc_v2'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/mlx5.dir/verbs.c.o: in function `mlx5_alloc_pd':
/home/nurlan/rdma-core/providers/mlx5/verbs.c:153: undefined reference to `cuMemAlloc_v2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [providers/mlx5/CMakeFiles/mlx5.dir/build.make:501: lib/libmlx5.so.1.24.48.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1560: providers/mlx5/CMakeFiles/mlx5.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

Anyone encountering similar problem before or knowing the solution to this problem?

Comment: You will need to add the CUDA driver api stub library to the linker search path

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Expanding on @talonmies valid comment/answer</sub>

### Part I: The lower-level error and solution

When you get an error of the form:

```
/usr/bin/ld: somefile.o: in function `func1`... undefined reference to `func2`
```

this is a [linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3322911/1593077). That means the compilation of your source files has succeeded (and, in particular, relevant header files were found); but the linking of the resulting object files into an executable has failed, since no compiled code has been found for a function named `func2`.

That can mean one of several things, but perhaps the most likely cause is that the linker just hasn't been directed to where the relevant library is located. It has the files *you* have compiled, but even when you give it the relevant library names with `-lfoo` for each library - it still needs to know where to look for the file `libfoo.a` (or `libfoo.so` etc). The linker can be told that either using `-L/path/to/library/files/` command-line arguments, or via the [`LIBRARY_PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297589/34868) environment variable.

In your case, the `cuMemAlloc()` is a CUDA Driver API function. So, you need to mention the directory in which your CUDA driver library access library is located. Typically, the driver library is at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so` (depends on your platform of course) - if it is installed. But the CUDA distribution itself has a stub driver library, at `/usr/local/cuda-12.2/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so` (assuming that's where you installed CUDA), which you should also be able to link against. So, your linker command line needs a `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` or something like a `-L/usr/local/cuda-12.2/lib64/stubs` argument.

### Part 2: Fixing things within CMake

When using CMake to configure your build, you achieve the effects described above with a higher level of abstraction and less detail. That is, you mostly avoid setting specific command-line arguments yourself, and rather define appropriate target dependencies.

First - the `CUDA` package is deprecated in newer versions of CMake! See the explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66341005/1593077). So, instead of:

```
find_package(CUDA 12.2 REQUIRED)
```

we write:

```
find_package(CUDAToolkit 12.2 REQUIRED)
```

(see the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html) for this package.) Then we can use the targets that provides us:

```
target_link_libraries(some_rdma_target CUDA::cuda_driver)
```

or

```
target_link_libraries(some_other_rdma_target CUDA::cudart)
```

(or both, depending on which target)
This should take care of all of the `-I`  command-line arguments for the compilation and the `-l` and `-L` command-line arguments for the linking. You should not have to add any of these yourself to the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` or or `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Comment: Did not help me. Specifically, I added -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/stubs, but still I get the same error.  I guess the libcuda.so cannot be linked.

Comment: @NurlanNazaraliyev: 1. Try the non stub. 2. Try doing it the "CMake way".

Comment: I tried the non stub. But still did not work for me.